# Greedy buffering on react native video

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a react native app with a feed of news and videos. When I open the app the videos are getting fully loaded and not buffered. Some users complain about the heavy bandwidth usage.

I already tried the `preferredForwardBufferDuration` for iOS but this seems to have no effect. I also tried to move to HLS streaming, but even with this setup all `.ts` chunks get loaded as soon as possible. I inspect the network with the charles http proxy.

Is there a way to buffer videos just 5 seconds in react-native for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute `preferredForwardBufferDuration` +-15 seconds

[See Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1643630-preferredforwardbufferduration).